# Are dash cams illegal in Austria?

Tags: legal, driving, austria

There are several sites, which claim that dash cams are illegal in Austria and, in fact, in a number of European countries:

https://www.which.co.uk/news/2018/08/using-your-dash-cam-abroad-what-you-need-to-know-about-driving-in-europe/

https://gb.snooper.eu/blog/can-i-use-my-dash-cam-in-europe/

However, there appears to be discussions elsewhere, which say they are OK:

https://www.quora.com/Why-is-using-a-dash-cam-illegal-in-Austria

Can anybody tell, what is actually the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no Austrian laws or regulations directly related to dash cams. Just as in many other countries, privacy concerns and the right to surveillance of own property must be weighed against each other.

The Supreme Administrative Court of Austria [confirmed in a verdict in 2016](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokumente/Vwgh/JWT_2015040011_20160912J00/JWT_2015040011_20160912J00.pdf) that the violation of privacy is excessive and that using dash cams is not permitted.

Comment: Would that translate into claims such as on the sites listed that merely possessing a dash cam would be punishable by a €10000 fine?

Comment: @Gnudiff I don't see why possessing a dash cam should be punishable. A dash cam is not inherently different from any other video camera. The issue is using it as a dash cam, not possessing it or using it for other purposes.